# Lazy setting of model attributes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a model which is generated by parsing a data file. There are several interesting values which are not present in the original data file but can be derived from the ones that are.

However, many of these derived values are expensive to compute, so I would like to store them in the database once they have been computed.

I have tried to this:

```
def profit
  if not self[:profit]
    update_attribute :profit, expensive_computation
  end
  self[:profit]
end
```

Unfortunately, that only gets half the job done. The computed value gets stored, but every time I call profit, it computes the value again.

UPDATE:

Turns out the problem was not in the method, but in a find_by_sql statement earlier on that had Rails confused about the id's of the models. The code I ended up with was this:

```
def profit
  unless read_attribute(:profit)
    update_attribute(:profit, expensive_computation ) 
    self.save!
  end
  read_attribute(:profit)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You create a new method and remove the reading logic from it. Maybe something like this

```
 def update_profit
    update_attribute :profit, expensive_computation
 end
```

That way you can separate the reading logic and just use the method to get `profit` that rails gives you.

```
 @model.profit
```

Where @model is an instance of whatever class the attribute `profit` is in.

Answer (score 1):

```
def profit
  super || update_attribute(:profit, expensive_computation)
  return super
end
```

If the profit column has information in it, simply call the object's original profit method, which would return the contents of the `profit` column from the database.

Otherwise, (i.e. the `profit` column has a value of `nil`) use the `update_attribute` method to compute the `profit` value and store it to the database, then simply return the value from the database again.

If you would rather get the value of `profit` if it's already in the database or just `true` if the expensive computation has run, just do this (`update_attribute` returns true or false):

```
def profit
  super || update_attribute(:profit, expensive_computation)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Where the code should go is going to depend on when it's possible to calculate the profit (e.g. as soon as the record is first being saved, or will it sometimes be later?), and whether the profit can ever change.

In general it probably be best to put the calculation in some sort of `before_create`/`before_save` call that saves it only when it's possible to be calculated and/or has changed

vrish88 is right that you should probably leave the `profit` method alone unless you really need to calculate this on-the-fly as the data is needed. If that's really what you need, try:

```
def profit
  update_attribute(:profit, expensive_computation) unless read_attribute(:profit)

  read_attribute(:profit)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. My first thought is: do you have a typo in the `if not self[:profit]` line?